# Normal Distribution: Covariance of sample mean and sample

Tags: statistics

$X_1,\ldots,\overline{X}_N$ is a random sample of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ observations. Let $\overline{X}_N$ denote the sample mean. What is $\operatorname{cov}(X_1, \overline{X}_N)$?

Since the mean of $X_1$ is a sample in the larger sample $\overline{X}_N$, what do I do with this?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: There seems to be a typo: I presume you meant $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, thank you for editing! I will look at the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We know the mean of $X_1$ and $\bar{X}_N$, so all we need is 
$$E\left(X_1\left(\frac{1}{N}(X_1+\cdots +X_N)\right)\right).$$
Multiply through, and use the linearity of expectation.

We will need $E(X_1^2)$, which can be found from the known variance of $X_1$. We will also need $E(X_1X_i)$ for $i\ge 2$. This is easy to find, by independence.

Comment: Thank you so much André, I will need to look at your answer a bit more to fully understand, but thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. I left things to do that I am guessing you can handle. If you have difficulty with anything, please leave a message. There may not be an immediate answer, for I will be away for several hours.  The covariance will turn out to be very simple,

Comment: Thank you again! I am now stuck at E(X_1^2). Is the known variance of X_1: 1/N-1 ∑(X_1-X\bar)^2. I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I'm also terribly sorry about my formatting, I'm really trying to get it right but I think I need some more practice.

Comment: @bvnordling:  Recall that in general $\text{Var}(W)=E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$. For $X_1$ we therefore get $\sigma^2=E(X_1^2)-\mu^2$, so $E(X_1^2)=\sigma^2+\mu^2$.

Comment: So you will find that the expectation in the displayed formula of my answer is $\frac{1}{N}(\sigma^2+\mu^2+(N-1)\mu^2)=\frac{\sigma^2}{N}+\mu^2$. For the covariance, we subtract $E(X_1)E(\bar{X}_N)$, that is, $\mu^2$ from this and  simply end up with $\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$.

Comment: Thank you immensly for your help André, and for clarifying your answer. Also, the end result is intuitively reasonable - so hopefully I can move forward with confidence. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome.  I added some calculations in comments, since you seemed to have remaining uncertainties.